# Opencart - How to print a message when the Flat Rate shows up in cart?

Tags: php, printing, echo, opencart

I am using the latest **Opencart 3.0.3.8**

If you be so kind, I would like to know how can I **print** or **echo** a message when the ***Flat Rate Pop Up*** window shows up.

e.g "Spend another x amount to qualify for Free Shipping"

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPsvM.png)